# What does valid until means (Dubai visa)?

Tags: visas, dubai

I applied for my Dubai visa (GCC resident) 30 days. I already got the E-Visa.

Entry permit# ######## / 2016 / 214
Date & Place of Issue: Dubai Sept. 28, 2016
Valid until: Oct. 27, 2016

My flight in Dubai is on Nov. 6, 2016. Did I apply for the visa too early? What does the valid until means? If this E-Visa is valid until oct. 27, 2016 that means I need to apply for a new one?

Comment: According to dubaivisa.net a GCC Residents Entry Permit can be used for entry within 60 days from the date the visa is issued. The stay period is 30 days from date of entry. From that it seems odd that you received a only valid for 30 days

Comment: For Dubai, the visa has two validities. One is how long you have to travel on it (the expiry date) and the other is how long you can stay on it (the duration of stay). Only the expiry date (Valid Until:) is written, and the duration starts once you enter the country; but you have to cross the border before the Valid Until date.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to apply for a new visa. Your visa will already have expired by the time you land and you will be inadmissible.

In fact, you may be denied boarding.